# SwiftUI - How to make a class have a menu?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a button (chevron) that shows at the side of a search bar like this:

[image]

This button has a lot of customizations, so I decided to give it its own class, to reduce code pollution and make the code neat.

This is the class's body...

```
var body: some View {

    Button(action: {
      onTap()
    }) {
      Image(systemName: "chevron.right.square").renderingMode(.original)
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .foregroundColor(color)
    }
    .font(fontSymbol)
    Spacer().frame(width: 10)
  }
```

The `Image` inside a `Button` is just me trying other options. I have created this as just the image without the button too.

The problem is this:

1. I will create an instance of this class on the main view.
2. I want that to display a menu when it is tapped.

This is how I am using it on the main class

```
MenuButton()
.contextMenu {
      Button(action: {
      }) {
        Text("option 1")
      }

      Button(action: {
      }) {
        Text("option 2")
      }

      Button(action: {
      }) {
        Text("option 3")
      }

    }
```

This is the result...

[image]

The box is shown already expanded in height.

I was expecting a popover to appear only after tapping on the chevron and that popover to be pointed to the chevron or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spacer to locate button where it should be

```
.font(fontSymbol)
//Spacer().frame(width: 10)   // << this one
```

and context menu works by long press as expected